# Text labels in image pixel coordinate system in VisPy

Tags: python, visualization, vispy

I don't see an example or straightforward answer in VisPy documentation. I would like to display an image with text labels and other markers attached to image pixels. Assume that the pixel size is 1 x 1, the text has real (non-integral) coordinates and scales with the image when zooming. Here is a sample screenshot of a highly zoomed image with four whole pixels visible and markers attached to them:

[image]

I'm looking for clues of doing a similar thing with VisPy or another Python visualization library.

I would like to place objects (image, text, arrow, etc.) in a common real coordinate system different from integral coordinates of a window. The image would be a grid of 1 x 1 squares. The text would have a height smaller than one, about 0.07 on the picture above. The objects would get their position and size when constructed, so there would be no need to use chains of transformations to describe a scene.

I modified one of the examples:

```
canvas = scene.SceneCanvas(keys='interactive', size=[1000, 1000])
canvas.show()
view = canvas.central_widget.add_view()
image = scene.visuals.Image(read_png('lena.bmp'), parent=view.scene)
t1 = scene.visuals.Text('42', pos=[0, 0], parent=image, color='red', font_size=8)
a1 = scene.visuals.Arrow(pos=[[3,3],[7,9]], parent=image, color='blue')
view.camera = scene.PanZoomCamera(aspect=1)
view.camera.flip = (0, 1, 0)
view.camera.set_range()
view.camera.zoom(0.5, (0, 0))

app.run()
```

but `a1` arrow doesn't show, text doesn't scale (expected) and I don't know how to align the image with the window when it is first displayed:

[image]

Adding more than a handful of objects takes a long time on a fast PC. This example takes about 4 mississippies to the first render:

```
for x in range(9):
  for y in range(9):
    _ = scene.visuals.Text('42', pos=[x,y], parent=image, color='yellow', font_size=8)
```

Aggregating text visuals makes it run much faster, but it is still unusable for real life data size. This code sample, where `W, H = 512, 512` takes over 13s from calling `app.run()` to displaying graphics inside the window.

```
canvas = scene.SceneCanvas(keys='interactive', size=[1000, 1000])
canvas.show()
view = canvas.central_widget.add_view()
pixels = read_png('lena.bmp')
image = scene.visuals.Image(pixels, parent=view.scene)
W, H, _ = pixels.shape
labels = [str(randint(0, 255)) for _ in range(W*H)]
pos = [[x, y] for x, y in itertools.product(range(W), range(H))]
text = scene.visuals.Text(labels, pos=pos, parent=image, color='green', font_size=8)
view.camera = scene.PanZoomCamera(aspect=1)
view.camera.flip = (0, 1, 0)
view.camera.set_range()
view.camera.zoom(0.5, (0, 0))

app.run()
```

Once displayed, zooming and panning is snappy.

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working? The traditional way of making to different Visuals align is to work with Transforms by doing `my_visual.transform = STTransform(scale=(x_scale, y_scale, z_scale), translate=(x_translate, y_translate, z_translate)`. In combination with specifying appropriate positions to the Visual you can usually get the data to show up where ever you want.

Comment: @djhoese I'm missing the fundamentals of VisPy, e.g. coordinate systems. What are the coordinates of a new `vispy.visuals.image.ImageVisual`?

Comment: The coordinate system for the ImageVisual (0 to num_columns, 0 to num_rows). I don't remember right now it is is inverted in the y-dimension which would match common practice for displaying images. You'd want to do `image.transform = STTransform(scale=...)` to get it to your preferred coordinate range. For performance with a lot of Visuals see: https://vispy.org/faq.html#why-is-my-visualization-slower-when-i-add-more-visual-objects
  You may also need to worry about drawing order as you have all your visuals on the z=0 plane which may result in OpenGL not drawing the right thing on top.

Comment: @djhoese Is there a way to combine text visuals? I edited my question with an example of 91 text visuals, which is extremely slow.

Comment: I don't usually do this, but looking at the AxisVisual as a starting point, it looks like you can provide a list of strings as the `.text` for a TextVisual and then also specify a list of positions for each of those text elements. https://github.com/vispy/vispy/blob/efa49b6896321374149998e15f8bce2ae327ba70/vispy/visuals/text/text.py#L383-L385

Comment: @djhoese I aggregated the text visuals, see updated post, but the setup time is prohibitively long.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the 13s is from `app.run()` onward? Or does the initial creation of the `labels` and `pos` variables take a long time? The only other thing I can think of is converting `pos` to a numpy array which is done internally anyway: https://github.com/vispy/vispy/blob/efa49b6896321374149998e15f8bce2ae327ba70/vispy/visuals/text/text.py#L503-L507

You could also try passing `method='gpu'` to the TextVisual which uses a different rendering method that may be helpful.

Comment: @djhoese Yes: 0.5s before `app.run()` and 13s inside it to rendering complete. I tried `method='gpu' ` and it still takes 13s to render.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to start writing an answer because the comments are getting a little long. The main issue you are currently having is that it takes to long to display the TextVisual. I updated your example so it didn't depend on an external image source and it now looks like this:

```py
from vispy import scene, app
import numpy as np
import itertools

canvas = scene.SceneCanvas(keys='interactive', size=[1000, 1000])
canvas.show()
view = canvas.central_widget.add_view()
pixels = np.zeros((500, 500, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
image = scene.visuals.Image(pixels, parent=view.scene)
W, H, _ = pixels.shape
labels = [str(np.random.randint(0, 255)) for _ in range(W*H)]
pos = [[x, y] for x, y in itertools.product(range(W), range(H))]
text = scene.visuals.Text(labels, pos=pos, parent=image, color='green', font_size=8)
view.camera = scene.PanZoomCamera(aspect=1)
view.camera.flip = (0, 1, 0)
view.camera.set_range()
view.camera.zoom(0.5, (0, 0))


app.run()
```

And produces an image (after scrolling out) like this:

[image]

That is **a lot** of text and it is possible that vispy's text visual isn't optimized to display this much all at once. You can verify that it is the TextVisual preparing for drawing by adding this right before the `app.run()`:

```py
print("Before prepare draw")
text._prepare_draw(None)
print("After prepare draw")
```

I then added some print statements inside the code and discovered that out of the ~13 seconds it takes to prepare the text visual, almost all of the time is spent on this one numpy concatenate:

https://github.com/vispy/vispy/blob/d0d40f9ba4033e89f4110fa8f26ed126f7d1b243/vispy/visuals/text/text.py#L527-L529

```py
self._vertices = np.concatenate([
                _text_to_vbo(t, self._font, self._anchors[0], self._anchors[1],
                             self._font._lowres_size) for t in text])
```

If we can make that faster then this wouldn't be an issue. I'm just not sure how possible that is though.

Comment: I rearranged some of the code in text.py on the assumption that the np.concatenate was the slow part, but it really is just all in the `_text_to_vbo` function and iterating through the long list in of text in `text`. This is a doozy.

Comment: Just adding a data point. I have a similar test in C++ using raylib and the setup runs at 60 fps with no problems: 
`for (int i = 0; i < image.width; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < image.height; j++)
          DrawTextEx(font, format("({},{})", i, j).c_str(), {i, j}, 0.3, 0, RED);`

Comment: Yeah, we're doing for loops over every character of 250000 strings in python. It isn't going to be fast.